# shorthand for angular dependency between attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following situation

```
directives.directive('x', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            a: "=",
            b: "="
        },
        controller: function($scope){
            if((angular.isDefined($scope.a) && !angular.isDefined($scope.b))
                || (!angular.isDefined($scope.a) && angular.isDefined($scope.b))){
                throw new Error('a and b need to be specified');
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I have a problem with my `if` inside the controller. As you may see, it is kind of hard to read it and it's not very efficient.

What it is trying to do is to see if both `a` and `b` were defined on `$scope`. They can both miss but if one of them is specified, the other one must become mandatory.

Is there a better way to write this?

**Later edit:**
Lets also things about when case of having three variables on scope and we need the same behavior. How will you proceed?

Comment: try `if(!$scope.a != !$scope.b)`

Comment: it would behave like a xor operator, but for understanding code easily I would go for what you have written, although it is very verbose.

Comment: I like your responses but I had a problem in my code. I made the correction, it was `isString` instead of `isDefined` for `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function isUndefined

```
if(angular.isUndefined($scope.a) || angular.isUndefined($scope.b))
        {
            throw new Error('a and b need to be specified');
        }
```